# background display

Tags: nexus-6

I have a nexus 6 and when I now make phone calls my background screen goes black and I cant access my phone screen to do anything like use the keypad or hang up the call ? I have tapped the screen try the up and down volume keys even tried the power off button

any suggestions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with the proximity sensor on the phone. Download an app like [Phone Tester](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mtorres.phonetester&hl=en_GB) to test if the proximity sensor if functioning correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the solutions mentioned here: [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982571/disable-proximity-sensor-during-call)

You can make changes in your build.prop or you can download an app that takes care of it for you.